# Sorting NSString which value save in NSMutableDictionary

Tags: ios

I am show NSMutableDictionary value in uitextview . but the value is not save in order by order like my code is :-

```
NSMutableArray *entries= [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Row 1", @"Row 2", @"Row 3", @"Row 4", @"Row 5",@"Row 6",@"Row 7",@"Row 8",@"Row 9", nil];
selectionStates = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];


-(void)done:(NSString *)aValue

{

[txtViewComponents resignFirstResponder];

NSString *compontentText = @"";
for(int i = 0; i< selectionStates.allKeys.count; i++)
{
    int val = [[selectionStates objectForKey:[selectionStates.allKeys objectAtIndex:i]] intValue];
    if(val == 1)
    {
        compontentText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ \n%@", compontentText,[selectionStates.allKeys objectAtIndex:i]];

    }
}
if([compontentText hasPrefix:@" "])
    compontentText = [compontentText substringFromIndex:2];
txtViewComponents.text = compontentText;
```

}

output is:
Row 2
Row 4
Row 6
Row 8
Row 1
Row 3
Row 5
Row 7

I want:
Row 1
Row 2
Row 3
Row 4
Row 5
Row 6
Row 7
Row 8
please help me if any one have any idea.

Comment: can you show the result of `selectionStates`

Comment: Row 2 Row 4 Row 6 Row 8 Row 1 Row 3 Row 5 Row 7

Comment: why you are not tried in this place `NSMutableDictionary` of array , the reason nsdictionary does not retrun the value in the same order , in my suggestion in here use `NSMutableArray`

Comment: is entries are in selectionStates??? like [selectionStates objectForKey:@"???"] wht is key??

Answer (score 0):

```
 entries = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[entries sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)]];
```

Comment: i have NSMutableDictionary

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. - [From review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/11679370)